# GAE "500 Server Error" message when trying to load my application

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm not sure which log to look at, but in general, all the errors are the same as this paste. I recently upgraded my client machine to Python version 2.7.8, from 2.7.7. The app runs locally.

```
E 22:20:58.694 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 302, in _LoadHandler
    raise err
ImportError: <module 'blog' from '/base/data/home/apps/s~eminent-augury-789/1.380687153152922933/blog.pyc'> has no attribute application
```

Comment: Are you saying that this worked under 2.7.7, but not under 2.7.8? Can you show the first part of your `app.yaml`?

Comment: I would try `pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client` _with sudo if necessary_ to make sure that the app engine is current with your python version.

Comment: Show the contents of app.yaml and the application definition in blog.py.  Look at the specifics of the ImportError. "has no attribute application"  so you app.yaml is probably referring to blog.application.  Check that it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work under 2.7.7, I was getting the same error. I created another project, with a different project id, and it works. I'm guessing that the app.yaml file was corrupt and I just couldn't find the problem. I upgraded app engine before I started this. I use VIM, for editing. I used the same project id for different projects, just changed the version number, not sure if that was the problem, either. I don't know how to cut and paste in code samples, they get formatted differently, let me work on that and I'll paste the app.yaml file in.